# Child and its children not being re-rendered

Tags: angular

I have an angular 5 parent component whose template looks like

```
<parent-component>
<child-component [data-from-parent]='data'> </child-component>
<button (click)="updateChildData()"></button>
</parent-component/>
```

The child-component and parent-component are

```
@Component({   
    selector: 'child-component',
    styles: [`
    `] 
    templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent {
   @Input() data-from-parent: any; 
   ...
}

@Component({   
    selector: 'parent-component',
    styles: [`
    `] 
    templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent {
   data: any;
   ...
   updateChildData() {
      this.data = JsonDataFromARestCall();
   }
}
```

The child-component is itself composed of 4 or five children components.

The data-from-parent input is json that is retrieved through a rest call by the parent. This json contains several key-values that are used by the child-component and its own children as arguments to make other rest calls.

Whenever the parent component updates the data I checked that ngOnChanges() of the child is called but neither the child nor its children is re-rendered.

I tried to inject ChangeDetectorRef in the child and call its detectChanges method in ngOnChanges but it made no difference.

Shouldnt the entire child and its children components re-render every time the input bound data changes?

Comment: As long as the json is 'just' a string, it will not update the child component. You need to pass it as an Object. Simple datatypes are not passed as reference. You may be able to transform the json into a map like `data: Map<string, string>` ? That should work as expected..

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept input property changes with a setter. Assuming that the type of `data` is an object, change your child component to the following,

```
export class ChildComponent {
   _dataFromParent: any;

   @Input('data-from-parent') set dataFromParent(data: string) {
      this._dataFromParent= data;
   };
   ...
}
```

Now you can use `_dataFromParent` in your child component